# IntelliJ Idea Services panel missing/invisible

Tags: intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ set up to work with a SQL database. Normally, when I execute queries, the results show up in the `Services` panel.

Right now, though, the only thing that appears is this minimize button in the middle of the screen. Hovering over it shows the text "Hide Shift + Escape". If I click it, it disappears.

[image: screenshot of panel]

I've tried clicking the `Services` button in the bottom toolbar, but that just toggles the visibility of this button. I also tried restarting IntelliJ and choosing `Window > Layouts >  Restore Current Layout`, both to no avail.

How do I get the window back?

Comment: Please try to right click on "Services" in the bottom toolbar and select "View Mode - Docked". Aren't there possibility to expand window by dragging borders?

Comment: @y.bedrov that worked, thanks! I got it with `View Mode > Dock Pinned`. Makes so much sense in retrospect; I can't believe I didn't try right clicking it. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to right click on "Services" in the bottom toolbar and select "View Mode - Docked".